# Pynput sent mouse only press and won't release

Tags: python, python-multithreading, pynput

Hi I wanted to bind extra buttons on my mouse using pynput for playing a game

`Button.x1` for spam spacebar key

`Button.x2` for spam left mouse

and all of them is trigger

for `x1` button is worked. but the `x2` is more likely holding the left mouse button, when I activate it

I've tried run the script on terminal (as admin). but still won't work

here is my code

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button, Controller as MController
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KController
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from random import uniform

C_keyboard = KController()
C_mouse = MController()
state = [False, False]

def bind(i, key, c):
    global state
    while state[i]:
        c.press(key)
        sleep(round(uniform(0.5, 1.0), 10))
        c.release(key)

def onClick(x, y, button, pressed):
    global state
    global C_keyboard
    global C_mouse
    if pressed:
        if button == Button.x1:
            state[0] = not state[0]
            Thread(target=bind, args=(0, Key.space, C_keyboard)).start()
        elif button == Button.x2:
            state[1] = not state[1]
            Thread(target=bind, args=(1, Button.left, C_mouse)).start()
    print("%s is %s (%s, %s)" % (button, ("Pressed" if pressed else "Released"), state[0],state[1])) 

def main():
    with Listener(on_click=onClick) as listener:
        listener.join()
Thread(target=main).start()
```

here is the output of my `onClick` function when I pressed `x2` once

[image: output of my click function]